# How do I output multiple calculations with an m file as matrices?

Tags: matrix, iteration, matlab

I'm writing an m file where and iteration of answers are calculated.  I want to save each of these iterations in a matrix.  How do I go about doing this?

```
    j = 0;

for j < n;  %n is a user input
    futurevalue = P*(1+i)^j;  % each of these calculation I want to save
    j = j+1;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a cell array and store the desired variable in it.

```
intermResults = cell(1,n);
for j = 1:n;  %n is a user input
    intermResults{j} = P*(1+i)^j;  % each of these calculation I want to save
end
```

Afterwards you can access the value xx:

```
desiredIntermResult = intermResults{xx}
```

Btw. I didn't know MATLAB supports ++ operator.

*It doesn't. I changed the code so that it follows Matlab syntax - Jonas*

Comment: I would say there is no 'increment operator' like *++* in MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is. The original code is some weird C++/MATLAB combination :)